# Is whitespace allowed between \section and \index or \label?

Tags: macros, labels, white-space

Sometimes I need to add a label or index immediately after a new chapter/section/subsection, etc., and the code may look like:

```
\section{TITLE}  \index{INDEX}  \label{LABEL}
```

This works fine in my document. My section titles are set with `titlesec`, and to my experience this won't cause extra whitespace in the document, even when the section is in `runin` style.

However, I wonder if the whitespaces between them are actually (always) allowable. Are there some cases where they cause undesirable extra space in the document? In other words, is it always safe to write in this fashion?

Comment: the white space makes no difference but it's generally better to put them in the argument than after it